# Using LINQ Contains versus SqlMethods.Like

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

How do I replicate the following result in my LINQ query without calling in the helper library System.data.Linq.SqlClient?

```
Where SqlMethods.Like(e.POSITION, "%A[FGL]7%") _
```

I would like this query to be more purely LINQ if possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT:** based on my comments with Lette I initially missed the pattern matching which SqlMethods.Like supports.

Your query looks like VB so you can actually use the [Like operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) directly but you'll need to replace the `%` with an asterisk `*`:

```
Where e.POSITION Like "*A[FGL]7*" _
```

If you're using C# you'll need to either use [Lette's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165453/using-linq-contains-versus-sqlmethods-like/2169583#2169583) after calling `AsEnumerable()` to get the data into memory (perhaps filter on any other criteria first *then* call the regex for further filtration) or follow [Ruben's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165453/using-linq-contains-versus-sqlmethods-like/2169767#2169767).

The methods I mentioned below do not act 100% like the SqlMethods.Like method since the pattern is essentially escaped. In other words it only treats it as literal text.

---

Simply use the regular String.Contains method on it:

```
Where e.POSITION.Contains("A[FGL]7")
```

LINQ to SQL will translate .NET methods in this manner:

- text.**StartsWith(...)** = `LIKE ...%`
- text.**Contains(...)** = `LIKE %...%`
- text.**EndsWith(...)** = `LIKE %...`

Comment: Is this a Linq-To-Sql question? If so, you're probably correct. I'm under the impression that the OP wants a "pure" Linq solution.

Comment: @Lette I believe so since the OP is using the SqlMethods class which is only supported in LINQ to SQL (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355235.aspx).

Comment: The String.Contains method as described above returns no results.

Comment: @mmcglynn yes, it wouldn't since it doesn't recognize patterns the way `SqlMethods.Like` does. I realized this after posting it but kept it to show the difference. They would only be useful if you have a fixed string, not a pattern. Otherwise use the VB `Like` operator or `SqlMethods.Like`.

Answer (score 2):

**Clarification: This answer is written with the assumption that this is *not* a LINQ to SQL question. If it is, please turn to the other answer(s).**

For this to work, you would have to mimic the `Like` operator from SQL. This is in your case probably best done with a regular expression.

Here's an example:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

Regex regex = new Regex("^.*A[FGL]7.*$");

// assuming that 'e' is a sequence of elements of type Foo
IEnumerable<Foo> results = e.Where(foo => regex.IsMatch(foo.POSITION));
```

The `results` should now be filtered according to your needs.

Comment: It's important to note that using a regex in LINQ to SQL will throw a `NotSupportedException` since it "has no supported translation to SQL." The only way for this to work would be to use `.AsEnumerable()` on the table which is usually undesirable since the whole table would come across unfiltered. Regex is great but for this simple case the methods provided by the string class would suffice even if it weren't a LINQ to SQL query.

Comment: @Ahmad - You will have to remember that this answer is written with the assumption that it is *not* a linq-to-sql question. In this context the `string.Contains` would not suffice. The OP clearly wants to filter by a pattern.

Comment: I absolutely agree and I didn't mean to attack your answer. If this were L2S then my comment is valid. Otherwise your solution is perfectly valid. However, I disagree with your take on `String.Contains`. The pattern `%A[FGL]7%` is equivalent to your regex; ie it occurs anywhere in the string, so the string does "contain" it and `String.Contains` would work.

Comment: @Ahmad - No offense taken. I'm just saying that `AG7` matches the regex. `String.Contains` does not use patterns, so `AG7` does not *contain* `A[FGL]7`.

Comment: doh! I totally missed the [FGL] class and its relevance to LIKE. You're correct, the methods I mentioned do not take this into account (updated my response) and will not recognize patterns. I'm out of votes for another 45 mins so I'll def. +1 by then. Good catch :)

Answer (score 1):

Most LINQ providers support the VB `Like` operator, which does pretty much the same. From C# you can access this functionality through the **Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LikeOperator**'s **LikeString** method:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;

...

where LikeOperator.LikeString(e.POSITION, "*A[FGL]7*", CompareMethod.Text)
```

Do beware that VB's Like uses slightly different syntax than SQL's Like; notably it uses `*` and `?` rather than `%` and `_`. (LINQ to SQL translates this VB syntax to SQL syntax, though.)

(Don't forget to reference **Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll** though.)

Answer (score 0):

consider something like this for membership profile information:

```
matches = matches.Union(memberDB.aspnet_Profile
                    .Where("it.PropertyValuesString Like @first", new ObjectParameter("first", "%<FirstName>%" + firstName + "%</FirstName>%"))
                    .Select(p => p.UserId));
```