# LINQ contains appends % and escapes %

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm using LINQ to create dynamic sql, when I'm using contains I don't want it to prefix and suffix % and if I'm using % inside my string I don't want to escape it. It escapes the percentage signs added by me using ~ as prefix before % as escape sequence character

For instance:

```
string str = '%test%.doc%' 
.Contains(str) // converts this into LIKE '%~%test~%.doc~%%'
```

Expected Conversion: LIKE '%test%.doc%%'

Comment: example, string str = '%test%.doc%' this is my string .Contains(str) should take it as it is, not convert it to '%%test~%.doc%%' where ~ is specified as escape seq char

Comment: Which LINQ? LINQ to SQL?

Comment: LINQ to SQL and EF4 are different things. Which are you using?

Comment: Seems like I am not aware of the difference between two. But if I am not wrong, I'm using linq2sql

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165453/using-linq-contains-versus-sqlmethods-like and in general the `SqlMethods.Like` method which will enable you to do a custom `LIKE` with Linq-to-sql.

Comment: @lasseespeholt, can I use SqlMethods.Like inside lambda expression, because I'm using PredicateBuilder to build the sql query.

Comment: As John Saunders said - .Contains() maps to LIKE in SQL Server, wherefore your string is escaped with '~' - see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx - It is not clear whether you actually want to find something with % characters in it?

Comment: @TRK, sorry but I assume its clear look at my expected conversion...

Comment: Why do you expect it to look like that?

Comment: I simply cannot understand what it is you want to obtain. Linq2Sql escapes the string for you before it ships it to SQL Server. You should probably rephrase your question and explain the full story.

Comment: @11000011 You have to give examples. The class is located here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like.aspx Maybe you could google "sqlmethods like" to see examples...

Comment: @lasseespeholt, your solution for using SqlMethods.Like works, would you mind putting comment as an answer, I;ll accept that answer.

Comment: LINQ 2 Entities is what I'm using and the accepted answer is valid only in case of L2S not L2E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*as questioner asked, I've made my comments an answer*

See [Using LINQ Contains vs. SqlMethods.Like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165453/using-linq-contains-versus-sqlmethods-like) and in general the [SqlMethods.Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like.aspx) method which will enable you to do a custom `LIKE` with Linq-to-sql.

Simple example:

```
var res = from row in dc.Table
          where SqlMethods.Like(row.Column, "%A%A%")
          select row;
```

More examples with `Contains`,`StartsWith` and `Like`: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/16/linq-to-sql-like-operator.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Contains is probably translating into the use of the `LIKE` operator in SQL. This operator takes `%` as a wildcard character. `Contains("abc")` maps to `LIKE '%abc%'`.

Comment: yes, but I can't use .Equals as it will make use of = instead of LIKE. and also it will still escape % in my string. Please see my example in questions comments.

Comment: What is the exact problem this is causing? And, edit your question to make it clearer - don't use comments for that.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following extensions to avoid that case (although in my specific case, I'm still using wildcards, but you could modify it for your own effect).

```
public static bool Like(this string value, string term)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(string.Format("^{0}$", term.Replace("*", ".*")), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        return regex.IsMatch(value ?? string.Empty);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> Like(this IEnumerable<string> source, string expression)
    {
        return (from s in source where s.Like(expression) select s);
    }
```

Comment: Just saw that you're using L2S. Not sure if the extensions I posted will help in that case, but I'll leave the answer in case it's useful.

Comment: And to give credit where it's due, I originally came across the idea for these extensions on this post: http://www.devexpertise.com/2009/09/25/implementing-a-linq-version-of-sqls-like-operator/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't think of an easy way to do this, but this might work:

```
var a = from t in Db.Tests
        let i1 = t.Name.IndexOf("test")
        let i2 = t.Name.IndexOf(".doc")
        where i1 != -1 && i2 != -1 && i1 < i2
        select t;
```

Here is the equivalent in method chains:

```
Db.Tests.Select(t => new {t, i1 = t.Name.IndexOf("test")}).Select(
                @t1 => new {@t1, i2 = @t1.t.Name.IndexOf(".doc")}).Where(
                    @t1 => @t1.@t1.i1 != -1 && @t1.i2 != -1 && @t1.@t1.i1 < @t1.i2).Select(@t1 => @t1.@t1.t);
```